# Safari/jQuery returns 0 for height of block element

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm creating a jQuery plugin and I set the height onReady using:

```
$(elm).css({
    width: $(elm).attr("w"),
    height: $(elm).attr("h")
});
```

I also append elements to `$(elm)` and set their height as well:

```
$(elm).append(<c/>).find("c").css({
    "height": "180px"
});
```

Later on in the same method, I access the same value:

```
console.log(
    "Element Height: "+$(elm).height()+"\n"+
    "Circle Height: "+$(this).height()
);
```

Circle height shows 180, as it should, but element height shows 0.

This is only a problem in Safari. Why is this?

Comment: What does `console.log($(elm), $(elm).css("height"), $(elm)[0].style.height)` return ? Thanks for sharing

Comment: I encountered the same issue on Mac with Safari 5.1 and traced it down to the fact that the element was a `<main>` tag. Switching it with a `<div>` fixed it. Seems that Safari has issues calculating dimensions on HTML5/non-standard tags.